# Printer problem with UFW

Tags: printing

My printer is physically connected to my computer. Ubuntu has found the printer, but printing isn't working. Does it need localhost to be opened on UFW to work ?

Comment: You said that this is not a network printer. It has nothing to do with the firewall... Please, specify printer type and connection method in more detail.

Comment: The printer is a Samsung ML-1865W laser (no longer supported by Samsung). It is plugged in directly to my desktop PC. No server involved. Ubuntu has found the printer. If I click on "Additional Printer Settings" it says connected to localhost.

Comment: Point your browser at `http://localhost:631`. It's the CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) control interface. Use the Administration tab to add your printer.